# ClickOnce on a net6 Console + Web Project

Tags: asp.net-core, clickonce, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a kestrel enabled web app (I need to set up a web server listening on a custom port), but this should remain a console application that must be executed on our customers' PCs.

Everything's working as expected but I cannot use ClickOnce as publish profile. It just does not appear on Visual Studio 2022 publish profiles.

In my current configuration my csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Modifying that with:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

magically ClickOnce publish profile appears, but I cannot use kestrel and asp.net infrastructure (that I need), even adding the dependencies.

How can I force visual studio to allow ClickOnce also on Web Projects?

Or as an alternative (but the former is preferred), how can I run asp.net infrastructure without Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could stay with Microsoft.NET.Sdk and add a reference to the ASP.NET Core shared framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework

Your .csproj file should be something similar to this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```